# VB6: Double buffering/stop flickering on a movement animation

Tags: animation, vb6, double, buffer, flicker

Currently I have 6 images layered over top of each other, each with their own corresponding walk animation frame. Each time you walk the Visible property changes and allows the next animation frame to be seen.

The only problem is the bloody flickering when it is passing through any type of object be it, picturebox, form, command button, etc....

After a tiresome day of research I just can't come up with a solution  to fix this.

a little snippet of my code if anyone want's to see:

```
    Select Case CharFrame
Case 1

    Avatar(0).Visible = True
    Avatar(1).Visible = False
    Avatar(2).Visible = False
    CharFrame = CharFrame + 1
Case 2
     Avatar(0).Visible = False
    Avatar(1).Visible = True
    Avatar(2).Visible = False
    CharFrame = CharFrame + 1

Case 3
    Avatar(0).Visible = False
    Avatar(1).Visible = False
    Avatar(2).Visible = True
    CharFrame = 1
End Select

Sleep (Timer)

Avatar(0).Top = Avatar(0).Top + moveY
Avatar(1).Top = Avatar(1).Top + moveY
Avatar(2).Top = Avatar(2).Top + moveY

Avatar(3).Top = Avatar(0).Top
Avatar(4).Top = Avatar(1).Top
Avatar(5).Top = Avatar(2).Top

Avatar(6).Top = Avatar(0).Top
Avatar(7).Top = Avatar(1).Top
Avatar(8).Top = Avatar(2).Top

Avatar(9).Top = Avatar(0).Top
Avatar(10).Top = Avatar(1).Top
Avatar(11).Top = Avatar(2).Top
Loop

 Avatar(0).Visible = True
 Avatar(1).Visible = False
 Avatar(2).Visible = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this with Google:

```
Private Declare Function LockWindowUpdate Lib "USER32" (ByVal hwndLock As Long) As Long
```

When you like to stop window updating:

```
LockWindowUpdate <yourform>.hWnd
```

If you like to continue

```
LockWindowUpdate False
```

Found this, did not try it.